# I am facing this problem and I don't know how to solve it ( Syntax error at input '[' )

Tags: arrays, pine-script, fibonacci, tradingview-api, trading

fib_extension_levels = [0.0, 0.382, 0.618, 1.0]

The error is on the top line
error message : Syntax error at input '['

I tried to solve it myself but didn't know ...... Tried to solve it with chatGPT AI but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you declare arrays in pinescript. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html#declaring-arrays) documentation to learn how to declare arrays.

You can do:

```
fib_extension_levels = array.from(0.0, 0.382, 0.618, 1.0)
```